# Linking to "libOpenSLES" with MonoDroid

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, openal

Hi im doing a simple linking test for getting OpenAL/OpenSLES to work on MonoDroid in C#.
What is the correct lib name I should be linking to, because linking to "libOpenSLES" is saying it cant find the method "alutInit"??

NOTE: I'm testing this on a Android 4.0.3 tablet device.

Here is the simple test code::

```
public const string DLL = "libOpenSLES";
[DllImport(DLL, EntryPoint="alutInit", ExactSpelling=true)]
public unsafe static extern void alutInit(ALint* argc, ALbyte** argv);

public unsafe void Init()
{
    alutInit((ALint*)0, (ALbyte**)0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alutInit is part of ALUT library. Why do you thinkg OpenSLES will have it?

Comment: I was looking at this sample http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/a-guide-to-starting-with-openal-r2008

Comment: That link is about OpenAL. OpenSL ES is completely different library. Here is its documentation: http://www.khronos.org/registry/sles/specs/OpenSL_ES_Specification_1.1.pdf

Comment: Du, im stupid... was thinking it would be the same, silly me.  Ok, ill look for a sample on OpenSLES.